# BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync returning null

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

This is UWP code for getting BLE devices. Why I get bleDevice == null for some devices? I didn't find any documentation which explains that.

```
    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector());
    foreach (DeviceInformation di in devices)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(di.Name);
        BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(di.Id);

        if (bleDevice == null) {
            Debug.WriteLine("--- NULL ----");
            continue;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(bleDevice.Name);
    }
```

I noticed that I get bleDevice != null for BLE devices that HAVE exclamation mark with STATUS_DEVICE_POWER_FAILURE in device manager in Windows.

I get bleDevice == null for BLE devices that DO NOT HAVE exclamation mark in device manager.

Answer (score 18):

I got the same problem. the previous [answer from Chi Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429019/5011596) is in fact good but not enough detailed on how to do it (for non-experts;-) ).

Here the detailed process (assuming you have a c# project under Microsoft visual studio):

1. Double click the properties field under your project: this will open a new tab
   [image: select properties]
2. in the opened tab, select ***Application*** in the left then click ***Package Manifest...*** button
   [image: pkg manifest button]
3. A new tab named "*package.appxmanifest*" is opened. Select, inside it, the ***Capabilities*** tab
4. Check Bluetooth field under capabilities
   [image: select BT capability]
5. Save and recompile your project.

The BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(di.Id) will no more return null, **provided that you already have paired devices (either in your program or manually in Windows** .

Comment: I have to thank you very much for this simple solution. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the heck I was getting null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Bluetooth capability in your appxmanifest file.