# In UWP program, the client connection bluetooth (Ti bluetooth 4.0) equipment failure

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

On the Microsoft website to download a bluetooth communication demo,
Search to a bluetooth device can be successful, but the connection equipment failure. (picture 1 and picture 2)

In picture 1, the bluetooth devices have searched out, then I skip step 2, directly to step 3, the back would have failed.（Picture 2)

Then I found methods BluetoothLEDevice. FromIdAsync always returns null.
Also Microsoft's official website of the API documentation does not give the reason of the return value is null.（Picture 3）

In this case the address:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Warm prompt: (case of debugging environment)

System: win10 10.0.14393

IDE: vs2015

bluetooth devices: interface 4.0 （Texas Instruments）

System Settings: in win10 setting adjustment model for developers

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

I summarize the possible reasons:

① Bluetooth is not paired with the PC, so the device can not find the bluetooth service, I opened the device manager, found that the device did not find the service (Picture 4), but before doing Andrews Bluetooth development does not paired.

[image]
(Picture 4)

② Microsoft bluetooth communication API has a Bug

Search on the Internet three similar posts:

Post 1:[BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479747/bluetoothledevice-fromidasync-returning-null#new-answer?newreg=dd25a856cda3433d812861e3fb3f823d)

(Because the reputation is not enough so only a link)

Supplement：

In the case, I skip step 2 pairs directly responsible for the equipment connection, because I don't know PIN. Then I'd like to find a PIN bycrack，
but this step is encapsulated in Microsoft's API, can't be a secondary operation.

Bluetooth 4.0 most of the automatic matching function, so Android phone can be directly connected do not need to pair.
 So I guess Microsoft is not the method does not support automatic matching function.

(Finally, because of the prestige of my pictures can not upload.)

Answer (score 0):

Base this [official explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-dev-faq), you

**have to pair either through the Settings page or using the Windows.Devices.Enumeration APIs in order access these devices.**

> In the case, I skip step 2 pairs directly responsible for the
>   equipment connection, because I don't know PIN. Then I'd like to find
>   a PIN bycrack

Have you tried "0000" for the PIN?

**Update**:
Or, you can try use DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom and set its pair type to ConfirmOnly and no encryption. **Note**, [this will only work if the remote device does not require encryption or authentication to function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-dev-faq). You can reference Scenario9_CustomPairDevice of the official sample [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing). It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I have tired "0000" 、"1234" 、"8888"  for the PIN, but

Comment: I have tired "0000" 、"1234" 、"8888" for the PIN, but all failed. Now just don't know the PIN, and Microsoft does provide automatic matching. Do you have any good suggestion?

Comment: @Rocky You can try `DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly`, this will not require PIN while pairing. I tested with my BLE device and it works.

Comment: I called the mothed DeviceInformationPairing.TryRegisterForAllInboundPairingRequests(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly),but the return value is always false.
Enumeration DevicePairingKinds of the various enumeration values have tried, but the return value is always false. Microsoft did not give an explanation.

Comment: I try the method you said, the result was a failure, I think the problem is Microsoft API interface.